# google spreadsheet how do I auto fill only SOME values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following formula in the top cell:

`=SUMIF('Jan ''13'!D1:D165, A2, 'Jan ''13'!B1:B165)`

I need the next one to be:

`=SUMIF('Jan ''13'!D1:D165, A3, 'Jan ''13'!B1:B165)`

Unfortunately, Google auto fills this to:

`=SUMIF('Jan ''13'!D2:D166, A3, 'Jan ''13'!B2:B166)`

As you see, Google auto fills every value. Is there a way to limit this to certain ranges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `$` to either the row or the column (or both) to make it stay constant in a formula for autofilling.

You want this:

```
=SUMIF('Jan ''13'!$D$1:$D$165, $A2, 'Jan ''13'!$B$1:$B$165)
```

This formula would only increment the row part of the `$A2` of your formula. Everything else would stay the same.

From the looks of your question, the `$` before the column markers in my answer aren't strictly necessary, but I put them there just in case you decide to fill left/right instead of just up/down.

If you experiment with a bit, you'll find that you can any of these is valid for a cell: `$D$1` or `D$1` or `$D1` or `D1`. This applies to both the starting and ending cell for a range.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! You just saved me a few hours of my life :)

Comment: @UnoMeinAme Glad I could help. :)